# "Declaration or statement expected" Error in Angular2 (or TypeScript)

Tags: typescript, angular

I'm completely new to Angular2 and TypeScript. I'm following Tutorial but I keep coping this error. Is it an error caused by the compiler or something?

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It looks like you are using an older version of the compiler.

You need to download and install the [TypeScript 1.5 beta](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/107f89a0-a542-4264-b0a9-eb91037cf7af) (or newer) in order to use ES6 style imports and annotations.

You can check the version you currently have installed using:

```
tsc --version
```

It should give you `Version 1.5.0-beta`.

If you already have it installed, perhaps your `PATH` variable still points to the old folder, so edit your PATH variable to point to the latest folder, i.e.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.5\;
```

Comment: I was having the same issue. Switching to the new 1.5 beta release of tsc fixed it for me. @Chu Son, if this answer fixed your problem, you should select it as the accepted answer

Comment: You may also need to delete your old versions of TypeScript from the same directory Steve mentions above.

Comment: How to install the next version of tsc? tsc@next did not work!

Answer (score 3):

Since you didn't accept the answer, I assume you are on OSx?

I had 2 instances of TS installed on my machine, I needed to point to the correct/newer one. Try this:

In Webstorm goto Preferences (Command + ,) -> Languages -> Typescript.

**Command Line Options:**

> -m amd -t ES5

**Compiler Versions:**

> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/typescript/lib

This way it will grab your global typescript instead of the one Webstorm may have set to default for you.